# Vorticity Matrix for Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

I have a **markov chain** with **$Q(u,v)$** as transition probability matrix and **$\pi(u)$** as stationary distribution defined on state space $\Omega$. The dimension of matrix $Q$ is $nxn$ and vector $\pi$ is $1xn$.

I need to construct a **vorticity matrix $\Gamma (u,v)$** of dimension $nxn$ which has below properties

1. $\Gamma$ is skew symmetric matrix i.e, $$\Gamma (u,v) = -\Gamma (v,u) \quad ,\forall \, u,v \in \Omega $$
2. Row sum of $\Gamma$ is zero for every row i.e, $$ \sum_v \Gamma (u,v) = 0 \quad ,\forall \, u \in \Omega $$
3. Third property is, $$\Gamma(u,v) > -\pi (v)Q(v,u) \quad ,\forall \, u,v \in \Omega  $$

My question is : *How to construct vorticity matrix $\Gamma (u,v)$ which satisfies above three properties? I need to construct at least one such matrix*.

Is there any systematic way to build such matrices

**NOTE**: Transition probability matrix  $P$, and stationary distribution $\pi$ has below properties

Row sum of $P$ is one for each row,
 $$\sum_v P(u,v)=1 \quad ,\forall \, u \in \Omega$$
$\pi$ is probability distribution hence,
 $$\sum_v \pi(v) = 1$$
Stationary distribution condition for $\pi$,
 $$\sum_u \pi(u) P(u,v)  = \pi(v) \quad ,\forall \, v \in \Omega $$

Comment: Changing third property to $\Gamma \geq \epsilon + \dots$ for some small $\epsilon$, you can use LP for this.

Answer (score 1):

One can verify that the following matrix $\Gamma$ has the desired properties:
$\Gamma = [\pi]Q - Q^{\top}[\pi]$,
where $[\pi]$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements being the stationary distribution. This construction relates closely to the reversibility of a Markov chain as far as I know.

Comment: $\Gamma = [\pi]Q - Q^{\top}[\pi]$ , turns out to be zero matrix for simple random walk in which neighbour node is chosen uniformly


$$ Q = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ \pi = \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{2}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{2}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{10} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{10} \end{matrix} \right) $$

Comment: Since I can't add image of graph in comments, I am giving vertices and edges for graph. Vertex set V = {1,2,3,4,5}. Edge set E = { (1,2), (1,4), (2,5), (4,5), (3,4) }. All edges are undirected

Comment: That means your Q matrix represents a reversible Markov chain. In this case, $\Gamma$ is indeed zero. Actually, one checks whether a Markov chain is reversible by checking if $[\pi]Q=Q^\top[\pi]$. I am not aware of how to construct a non-zero $\Gamma$ matrix in this case.